# SQL - how to add every day a new column in 1 query without INSERT, UPDATE, etc

Tags: sql, sql-server, addition, cycle

I need to add every day to some query result a column A for sysdate, and next day as well, and next day as well, etc.
So you will have the same select which will always add for new day a new column for actual date.

Is this somehow possible in sql without using INSERT, UPDATE and other rewriting statements?

Thank you very much for your answers :)

Im using a Oracle SQL Developer

Comment: Do you really mean "column" (from left to right) or do you actually mean "row" (from top to bottom). Because if you want to add a column each day, your table will be extremely wide after a short time.

Comment: Can you show us a clearer example of what you want? You want to add a column to a table and then also have a dynamic query which will add the name of the new column to it, every day?

Comment: Yes, I really mean a column. It will be wide but this is what we need.

Comment: I need to add every day a same column(with just data for actual date) to same table result(not table itself). And I didnt thought about names of the columns, the Oracle in such cases just adds a number to it, and this option is for now OK with me

Comment: Why not just add rows and then use pivot to output it to the users?

Comment: Because I was wondering if I can do something like add Column sum(of something) for day 1,then add new column sum(of something) for day 2,...   so really adding columns, that would be cool :)

Answer (score 0):

SQL queries give you a fixed number of columns and a variable number of rows. If every day means more data to you then you would have a query to result in more rows usually. It's up to a GUI to display retrieved data in the most convenient way (one column per day in your example).

So, yes and no. Yes, you can (very easily) write a query to give you more data each day. No, you cannot write a query that results in a new column every day. But as mentioned, this is not what SQL is made for anyhow. SQL is the data retrieving language. You use a programming language or a report tool to display the data to your users.